# Map of channels

Tags: dictionary, go, channel

I'd like to index some channels based on a string. I am using a map but it won't allow me to assign a channel to it. I keep getting "panic: assignment to entry in nil map", what am i missing?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var things map[string](chan int)
    things["stuff"] = make(chan int)
    things["stuff"] <- 2
    mything := <-things["stuff"]
    fmt.Printf("my thing: %d", mything)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PYvzhs4q4S

Comment: You initialize a map with `make` or a map literal. Maybe go through the ["Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/) which covers all the basics.

Comment: Just a small clarification, in case:  The zero value of a map is nil.  As the answer states, you need to initialize it with `make`

Answer (score 18):

You need to initialize the map first. Something like:

```
things := make(map[string](chan int))
```

Another thing, you're sending and trying to consume from an unbuffered channel, so the program will be deadlocked. So may be use a buffered channel or send/consume in a goroutine.

I used a buffered channel here:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    things := make(map[string](chan int))

    things["stuff"] = make(chan int, 2)
    things["stuff"] <- 2
    mything := <-things["stuff"]
    fmt.Printf("my thing: %d", mything)
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/DV_taMtse5

The `make(chan int, 2)` part makes the channel buffered with a buffer length of 2. Read more about it here: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you put `chan int` in parentheses? The syntax `make(map[string]chan int)` works fine.

Comment: Oh, it was in the original code. I modified just the parts I had to modify.

Comment: @masnun could you tell us/me why do you use buffer size of 2 instead of 1? I tried with 1 and program still works.

Comment: This particular code example puts one thing and retrieves one thing. So `1` is fine here. I used `2` for no particular reason.